# Validating Swedish social security numbers (Luhn algorithm and dates)

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I've been writing code for some time but never had the need (or opportunity) to
write C/C++ code. Did a small project to learn some C++ and would appreciate feedback on code, testing, project structure and building.

### Project Layout

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── personnummer.cpp
│   └── personnummer.hpp
└── test
    ├── catch.hpp
    └── unittest.cpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(cpp-personnummer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/personnummer.cpp)

add_library(Personnummer ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Personnummer -lpthread)

add_executable(unittest test/unittest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(unittest Personnummer)
```

**src/personnummer.hpp**

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Personnummer {
int stoi_or_fallback(const std::string &maybe_digit, int fallback);

bool valid_date(int year, int month, int day);

int checksum(std::tm date, int number);

void collect_digits(std::vector<int> &digits, int num);

void collect_digits_pad_zero(std::vector<int> &digits, int num, int min_len);

struct Personnummer {
  std::tm date;
  int number;
  int control;
  char divider[1];

  bool is_valid_date() {
    return valid_date(date.tm_year, date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday);
  };

  bool is_valid_luhn() { return checksum(date, number) == control; };

  bool valid() { return is_valid_date() && is_valid_luhn(); };
};

bool from_string(const std::string &pnr, Personnummer &personnummer);
} // namespace Personnummer
```

**src/personnummer.cpp**

```cpp
#include "personnummer.hpp"
#include <regex>

namespace Personnummer {
bool from_string(const std::string &pnr, Personnummer &personnummer) {
  std::regex pnr_regex(
      "^(\\d{2})?(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})([-|+]?)?(\\d{3})(\\d?)$");
  std::smatch matches;

  int century, year;

  if (std::regex_search(pnr, matches, pnr_regex)) {
    century = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(1), 19);
    year = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(2), 0);

    personnummer.date.tm_year = century * 100 + year;
    personnummer.date.tm_mon = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(3), 0);
    personnummer.date.tm_mday = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(4), 0);
    personnummer.number = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(6), 0);
    personnummer.control = stoi_or_fallback(matches.str(7), 0);

    personnummer.divider[0] = *matches.str(5).c_str();
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

int stoi_or_fallback(const std::string &maybe_digit, int fallback) {
  try {
    return std::stoi(maybe_digit);
  } catch (...) {
    return fallback;
  }
}

bool valid_date(int year, int month, int day) {
  if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    return false;

  if (day < 1 || day > 31)
    return false;

  if (day > 30) {
    switch (month) {
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (month == 2 && day > 28) {
    bool is_leap_year = year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0);

    if (day != 29 || !is_leap_year) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

int checksum(std::tm date, int number) {
  std::vector<int> digits;

  collect_digits_pad_zero(digits, date.tm_year % 100, 2);
  collect_digits_pad_zero(digits, date.tm_mon, 2);
  collect_digits_pad_zero(digits, date.tm_mday, 2);
  collect_digits_pad_zero(digits, number, 3);

  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++) {
    int temp = digits.at(i);

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      temp *= 2;

      if (temp > 9)
        temp -= 9;
    }

    sum += temp;
  }

  return 10 - (sum % 10);
}

void collect_digits(std::vector<int> &digits, int num) {
  if (num > 9)
    collect_digits(digits, num / 10);

  digits.push_back(num % 10);
}

void collect_digits_pad_zero(std::vector<int> &digits, int num, int min_len) {
  // New vector for this section.
  std::vector<int> section_digits;

  // Collect the digits from given number.
  collect_digits(section_digits, num);

  // Add the potential padded zeroes.
  int missing_digits = min_len - section_digits.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < missing_digits; i++) {
    section_digits.insert(section_digits.begin(), 0);
  }

  // Add the padded section to final vector.
  digits.insert(digits.end(), section_digits.begin(), section_digits.end());
}
} // namespace Personnummer
```

**test/unittest.cpp**

```cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "../src/personnummer.hpp"
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Valid date", "[date]") {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> valid_dates = {
      {1990, 1, 1},  {1990, 1, 31},
      {1990, 2, 28}, {2016, 2, 29}, // 2016 is leap year
      {2020, 4, 30},
  };

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> invalid_dates = {
      {1990, 13, 1},
      {1990, 1, 32},
      {2017, 2, 29}, // 2017 is not leap year
      {2020, 4, 31},
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < valid_dates.size(); i++) {
    std::vector<int> test_case = valid_dates[i];

    std::stringstream case_title;
    case_title << "Testinv VALID: Y=" << test_case[0] << ", M=" << test_case[1]
               << ", D=" << test_case[2];

    SECTION(case_title.str()) {
      REQUIRE(
          Personnummer::valid_date(test_case[0], test_case[1], test_case[2]));
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < invalid_dates.size(); i++) {
    std::vector<int> test_case = invalid_dates[i];

    std::stringstream case_title;
    case_title << "Testinv INVALID: Y=" << test_case[0]
               << ", M=" << test_case[1] << ", D=" << test_case[2];

    SECTION(case_title.str()) {
      REQUIRE(
          !Personnummer::valid_date(test_case[0], test_case[1], test_case[2]));
    }
  }
}

TEST_CASE("Valid personal number", "[pnr]") {
  Personnummer::Personnummer p;

  std::vector<std::string> valid = {
      "6403273813",   "510818-9167", "19900101-0017", "19130401+2931",
      "196408233234", "0001010107",  "000101-0107",
  };

  std::vector<std::string> invalid = {
      "640327-381",
      "6403273814",
      "640327-3814",
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < valid.size(); i++) {
    std::stringstream case_title;
    case_title << "Testing VALID: " << valid[i];

    SECTION(case_title.str()) {
      REQUIRE(Personnummer::from_string(valid[i], p));
      REQUIRE(p.valid());
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < invalid.size(); i++) {
    std::stringstream case_title;
    case_title << "Testing INVALID: " << invalid[i];

    SECTION(case_title.str()) {
      REQUIRE(Personnummer::from_string(invalid[i], p));
      REQUIRE(!p.valid());
    }
  }
}
```

**test/catch.hpp**

Downloaded from [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2)

---

General feedback and reviews are very welcome but these are the main questions I had writing this:

- Does the code itself look OK? (It's formatted with `clang-format --style=llvm`)
- Are there any issues (big or small) that I've missed (bugs, memory leaks etc).
- How far off C++ pragma is it?

  - What would be a more C++ way of things?
- Is the way I split the code in files vs. headers a good/preferred way?
- Are the unit tests written in a good way (structure, location, naming, table driven)?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thanks! I'll look into that for some of the questions. My bullets were ment to be more like guidance to areas of interest and not to be seen as something I wanted one single person to look at and respond to all of them. The main hope here was to get some feedback on the code and I think a lot of the bullets are related to that.

Comment: @tinstaafl Well, I know what my code does so my questions are more related to the quality of the code. I also think it's of high importance to write good code to structure it right and use best practices. But after revisiting the Help Center I can see how I was off-topic so the question is now edited to include more relevant questions.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Sorry, forgot to edit that when removing the bullets. Updated now, hope this is more in line with the guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for how you might improve your code.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `std::string` which means that it should `#include <string>`.  It was not difficult to infer, but it helps reviewers if the code is complete.

### Know your tools

The CMake file starts with these lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(cpp-personnummer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

However, that's a problem because the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` wasn't intruduced until CMake version 3.1.  I'd recommend changing the `cmake_minimum_required` to 3.1.

### Don't link with unnecesary libraries

The CMake file currently contains this line:

```
target_link_libraries(Personnummer -lpthread)
```

First, the correct way to do this in CMake would be like this instead:

```
find_package(Threads)
target_link_libraries(Personnummer ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Second, and most importantly, it doesn't need to be done at all since nothing in there requires threads.

### Use standard classes where appropriate

Much of the date handling from the `Personnummer` class could be done more simply by using the `std::chrono::year_month_day` class.  For example, `valid_date` could be eliminated entirely in favor of [year_month_day.ok()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/ok) if your compiler supports C++20.

### Use CMake's test facility

CMake has test facilities built in.  I'd add the option to either build tests or not and in the top level `CMakeLists.txt` add this:

```
option(WITH_TEST "Build the test suite" OFF)
if (WITH_TEST)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

Now if you invoke CMake with `cmake -DWITH_TEST=1 ..` testing will be enabled.  If you then do `make` and then `make test`, you will invoke your test(s).  Note here that I've written `add_subdirectory`.  See the next suggestion for more on that.

### Use multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files

Instead of a single `CMakeLists.txt` file, it's easier to maintain if you create one per directory.  So the top level would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Personnummer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
option(WITH_TEST "Build the test suite" OFF)
add_subdirectory(src)

if (WITH_TEST)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

Now the one in `src` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
add_library(Personnummer "personnummer.cpp")
```

And the one in `test` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
include_directories(${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/src)
add_executable(unittest "unittest.cpp")
add_test(PersonnummerTest unittest)
target_link_libraries(unittest Personnummer)
```

Note that I've added the `include_directories` to point to the `src` directory.  More on that in the next suggestion.

### Don't hardcode project directory structures

In the current test program we have this line:

```
#include "../src/personnummer.hpp"
```

This buries a project configuration detail inside source code.  I recommend keeping those kinds of details out of the individual source files and instead point the tools (compiler, linker, etc.) to the appropriate directory instead.  That's why the `include_directories` was added to the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the `test` directory.  This way, if you decided to rename the `src` directory or move it elsewhere, the change could easily be made in just the CMake files instead of having to hunt through every source code file.  When there only a few, as with this small project, it might not seem like it makes much difference, but when you start working with large projects with thousands of files, following this advice will save you a great deal of time and frustration.

### Prefer iteration to recursion

The current definition of `collect_digits` is this recursive solution:

```
void collect_digits(std::vector<int> &digits, int num) {
  if (num > 9)
    collect_digits(digits, num / 10);

  digits.push_back(num % 10);
}
```

It's not faulty, but it isn't as efficient as it could be.  Generally, recursion is less efficient than iteration.  The reason is that pushing the the return address and both arguments onto the stack takes a bit more time and memory than simply doing this:

```
void collect_digits(std::vector<int> &digits, int num) {
  while ( ; num > 9; num /= 10) {
    digits.push_back(num % 10);
  }
  digits.push_back(num);
}
```

Better though, see the next suggestion.

### Rethink the interface

There are a number of specialized functions such as `collect_digits_pad_zero` that probably don't need to be part of the interface, or maybe shouldn't exist at all.  For example, `checksum` could be much simplified and wouldn't require either `collect_digits_pad_zero` or `collect_digits`.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
int luhn(std::string::iterator begin, std::string::iterator end) {
    int sum{0};
    for (bool even{true}; begin != end; ++begin, even ^= true) {
        int digit = *begin - '0';
        if (even) {
            if ((digit *= 2) > 9) {
                digit -= 9;
            }
        } 
        if ((sum += digit) > 9) {
            sum -= 10;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int Personnummer::checksum() const {
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
    ss.fill('0');
    ss << setw(2)
       << date.tm_year % 100
       << setw(2)
       << date.tm_mon
       << setw(2)
       << date.tm_mday
       << setw(3) << number;
    auto str = ss.str();
    return 10 - luhn(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Now we have two compact and useful functions.  Note also that `checksum` is a member function rather than a standalone function.

### Use `const` where appropriate

The functions `is_valid_luhn` and `valid` and `is_valid_date` are all non-modifying functions.  That is, none of them modify the underlying `Personnummer` object, so all of them should be declared `const` as with the `checksum` function above.

### Prefer `class` to `struct`

If there is not a compelling that `Personnummer` must have all of its data and functions public, it should be a class instead of a struct, and `from_string` should be a member function.

### Don't create pointless arrays

The `Personnummer` object definition currently includes this:

```
char divider[1];
```

That should just be this:

```
char divider;
```

### Use "range `for`" to simplify your code

The test code currently has these kinds of loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valid.size(); i++) {
  std::stringstream case_title;
  case_title << "Testing VALID: " << valid[i];

  SECTION(case_title.str()) {
      REQUIRE(p.from_string(valid[i]));
      REQUIRE(p.valid());
  }
}
```

First, you can use a range `for` to simplify, and second, there's no need for a `std::stringstream` here:

```
for (const auto& test_string : valid) {
  SECTION({"Testing VALID" + test_string}) {
    REQUIRE(p.from_string(test_string));
    REQUIRE(p.valid());
  }
}
```

This also assumes that the `from_string` function has been made a member function, as mentioned earlier.

### Use classes to simplify your code

The test cases for "Valid date" use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as the collection of test cases.  I'd suggest using a class there instead:

```
struct FakeDate {
  int year, month, day;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const FakeDate& fd) {
      return out << "Y=" << fd.year << ", M=" << fd.month << ", D=" << fd.day;
  }
};
```

Now the collections can be `std::vector<FakeDate>`.  Using the same range `for` as in the previous suggestion, we have:

```
for (const auto& test_case : valid_dates) {
  std::stringstream case_title;
  case_title << "Testing VALID: " << test_case;

  SECTION(case_title.str()) {
    REQUIRE(
        Personnummer::valid_date(test_case.year, test_case.month, test_case.day));
  }
}
```

### Be careful with signed vs. unsigned

The current `valid_date` code takes `int`s for the month, day and year.  Is it intended that negative values for the year do not make the date invalid?  If not, I'd suggest either checking for negative values or using only unsigned integers for each.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really the things I wanted to know more about! It felt bad writing my own date validator but I'm stuck with C++14 (macOS) so no `chrono` for me. Besides that, I adapted most of your suggestions. If you're interested the updated result can be found [here](https://github.com/bombsimon/cpp-personnummer). Again, thank you!

Comment: I’m happy you found it useful. That’s why we’re here!